# mySQL query - unique value using GROUP and HAVING

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

here's my sample data:

```
id  name      source
--------------------------
1   aaa       source1
2   bbb       source1
3   ccc       source1
4   ddd       source1
5   aaa       source2
6   bbb       source2
3   ccc       source2
4   ddd       source2
7   eee       source2
```

I'm trying to query all records where the value from "name" only occurs once (is unique) - so the desired output would be:

```
id  name      source
--------------------------
7   eee       source2
```

I've tried a combination of `GROUP BY name` and `HAVING` but it didn't work

```
SELECT name, source, COUNT(*) AS total FROM data
GROUP BY name
HAVING total=1
```

any ideas?

PS: how can i filter for "source"? `WHERE source = "source2"` won't help ..

Comment: you question makes no sense as ccc and ddd are also unique names in your sample

Comment: oh thanks .. edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query works but with a FULL_GROUP_By

all columns that are not in the select need  a [aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE data (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(3),
>   `source` VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO data
>   (`id`, `name`, `source`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'aaa', 'source1'),
>   ('2', 'bbb', 'source1'),
>   ('3', 'ccc', 'source1'),
>   ('4', 'ddd', 'source1'),
>   ('5', 'aaa', 'source2'),
>   ('6', 'bbb', 'source2'),
>   ('3', 'ccc', 'source2'),
>   ('4', 'ddd', 'source2'),
>   ('7', 'eee', 'source2');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT name, MIN(source), COUNT(*) AS total FROM data
> GROUP BY name
> HAVING total=1
> ```

> ```
> name | MIN(source) | total
> :--- | :---------- | ----:
> eee  | source2     |     1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec98959663fbdab5f5c9a29b7dc39dad)*

Comment: thanks - how would it work to filter for source2? where source = "source2" will give a wrong result ..

Comment: this is a second question but basicqalyy you make it to a subquery https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=116f588c5f922ac56dccb2042040c68d

Answer (score 0):

You need to add source to the group by or remove it from the select or put it into a aggregate function otherwise it will throw a error.

Comment: mysql supports having total =1 see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=061445f3fc103416e14b7fb87897b74a the questions makes no sense as i wrote

Comment: @nbk thanks. I only had sql server at my desk and it threw a error, thought it was the same on mysql as well. I updated my answer based on your comment so as to not miss lead anyone.